# Problem in Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css, dynamic, menu, drop-down-menu

I am getting an issue with dynamic drop down menu.
Please check the screenshot.
[image]

here I am getting the child menu list fixed into right side to screen. It is not viewing correctly. I want to get this list either left side or upper the screen.

Sorry poor english. Hope You understand.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at: http://www.d1079363-74.cp.blacknight.com/dev/

In your HTML, you need to add another `class` to the submenu that should open on the right, like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu open-right">
```

Then add this new CSS:

```
#menu ul ul ul.open-right {
    left: -100%;
}
```

That should work, but I haven't looked at all your CSS. On the off chance that it doesn't work, try using `left: -100% !important;` instead. If that works, I'll have a look at how to fix the specificity without using `!important`.